# iphone app on windows or android mobile

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c, windows, cross-compiling

Can iphone apps run on windows or android phones?

Is there any tool or framework available?

Comment: That sounds highly unlikely... Maybe there are "unified" frameworks, but these OS have very different UI paradigms and it is IMO difficult to write a unified framework that doesn't make the apps look out-of-context in one or two of the OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Port iPhone application to Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633742/port-iphone-application-to-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap is also multiplatform.

Supports iPhone, Android, Windows Mobile, Blackberry, and more.

http://www.phonegap.com/

From their website:

> PhoneGap is an open source development
>   framework for building cross-platform
>   mobile apps. Build apps in HTML and
>   JavaScript and still take advantage of
>   core features in iPhone/iPod touch,
>   iPad, Google Android, Palm, Symbian
>   and Blackberry SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Native iPhone apps wont run on other devices. However, if you were to create an application using a framwork such as JQueryMobile which is a library which formats web applications to look similar to an application for the device.

Jquery mobile is written to support many mobile devices so depending on your requirements and whether you need access to the phone hardware (eg camera etc) then jqmobile might be for you.

Comment: This sounds like a late-night infomercial :)

Comment: that means if my application is developed in xcode environment than there is no chance to convert it ?

Comment: Hi Pooja, iPhone apps are written in ojective-c, android in java, and WM in .net. so they are all different languages. Another language to check out is .net mono, which is basically .net that can run on other devices, even iPhone which would mean alot of you codebase should work cross platform

Comment: ok, if you are writing a native app then you could have a common mono back end, and the equivalent mono-device front end. otherwise write a web application and use something like jq mobile