# Game SDK for android phones

Tags: iphone, android

Is there any game SDK for android games like Corona which can be used to release applications on android phones and iphones at same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633742/port-iphone-application-to-android).

Since that thread asks a slightly different question, I'll repeat the answer here:

1)[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
2)[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

(not in other thread, added here)
3)[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) 
4)[Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/)
5)[Shiva](http://stonetrip.com/)

There are two main risks of doing it this way-  One, at least at one point these third-party IDE's were supposedly in violation of Apple's TOS-  This was ironed out, but no guarantees that it won't happen again.

The other is that (as mentioned in the linked thread) you do risk delivering a least-common-denominator experience-  Instead of doing iOS-style things on iOS and Android-style things on Android, you can easily end up delivering whatever the tool knows how to do on both.  Consider biting the bullet and building the application twice (once on each platform).