# Porting iPhone App to Android platform

Tags: android, iphone, porting

I am trying to get my iPhone App on Android platform as well. I was wondering if there is anyway I can directly port my iPhone App or Code to Android? Do I need to write whole App from the scratch for Android platform or is there anyway I can reduce my work? Thanks.

Comment: duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633742/port-iphone-application-to-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to port apps between platforms, and there is no reason you would ever want to. Android and iPhone are two wildly varying platforms both with unique interfaces, api layers, design guidelines and all sorts. Where you would use a navigation bar in iPhone (for instance) with a logo/title in the centre, a back button on the left and other buttons on the right, you would use an action bar in Android with a logo/title on the left hand side and action buttons on the right, possibly with a drop down for extra buttons.

Obviously there are some concepts which are "shared", such as tabbed browsing (although this is being overtaken in android by the dashboard concept and other ways of navigating) you should never port between these two platforms. You should always start from scratch.

Same goes for cross platform frameworks... there is so much that's different and unique about the two platforms that you'd be writing so much platform specific code it wouldn't be worth trying to maintain just one code base.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the great explanation.

Comment: A very insightful answer, which touches on why mobile apps are slowly killing the open Internet, as described in this article:
http://www.tnl.net/blog/2012/03/03/i-killed-the-internet/
 Luckily, some major content providers have caught wise are moving away from native apps towards "thin" apps which are actually just rendering a HTML5 gui which is fetched from some server.

Comment: article = tldr. However in response to your comment, native apps always present a much better user experience than HTML5 rendered apps. I am used to using my Android phone in the native way and don't want to have to "learn" new things just to indulge those who want to create cross platform apps. Also loading external HTML into a webview is arduous. If I come across apps which do this (which are few and far between, for good reason) I usually uninstall them. I'd rather just access the website when I have to.

Answer (score -1):

I believe their isn't a program that ports it for you.

Android is written in Java, however, they also developed an NDK, that is based on C++.
So if you already wrote for the Iphone, then porting it to android with C++ (NDK) is probably easier for you then write it in Java.

You can use 3rd party tools to create apps that work in both. That's what Titanium and PhoneGap were aiming at. With the new changes to the SDK Agreement, those look like they're not really "legal" or at least violate the agreement.

However I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I assume you mean C++ not C#!